# Kial "-iĉ-" por viriĉoj en la iĉisma sistemo?

Tags: language-evolution, x-system

---

Kiam la iĉisma sistemo estis verkita, kial ili elektis *-iĉ-* por la virgenra sufikso? Ĉu tio havas iun originon de iu nacia lingvo?

Answer (score 8):

It was formed by analogy from words like *panjo* and *paĉjo*.

- -njo -> -in-
- -ĉjo -> -iĉ-

According to Vilborg, *-in-* is a germanic suffix, while *-ĉjo* and *-njo* are Russian. In Russian, the male suffix consonant is ŝ and for whatever reason, was changed to ĉ in Esperanto.

Comment: I guess this now begs the question "why did Zamenhof choose -ĉjo- for the masculine diminuitive" :)

Comment: Information added as requested.

Comment: Shouldn't it be -**n**jo → -in-?

Comment: La demando estas en Esperanto. Do, la respondoj ankaŭ devas esti en Esperanto.

Comment: Marcus - yes, it should be. I think that's how I wrote it initially but messed it up when adding the info from Vilborg. As far as posting language, I will check the meta board for the guidelines. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I don't mind if the answers are bilingual and I (as the one posing the question) don't mind that the answer is in English. Of course, not everyone speaks the "other" international language - that's why we have Esperanto, of course! 

Comment: I think a bilingual answer would make most sense here.

Comment: I'm new to stack exchange, but isn't this becoming a "meta" discussion (now meta-meta)?